# How to decrease the width of the PieChart in the module react-native-svg-charts

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-svg-charts

Since already thank you wanted to know if anyone knows how to decrease the width of Graph Pie, for it to get thinner I tried some properties in svg, but nothing works anyone could help

today I have this result I wanted to reach this result

## CURRENT

[image]

## EXPECT

[image]

current component

```
    <View style={styles.areaGraphic}>

      <PieChart style={{ height: '100%', top: 20 }} data={pieData} strokeWidth={0.2} />
      <Text style={{
        top: -50, left: 38, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold',
      }}
      >
        {data.label.name}
      </Text>
      <Text style={{
        top: -50, fontSize: 12, textAlign: 'center',
      }}
      >
        {data.label.description}
      </Text>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are to props for the PieChart component you can use:

**innerRadius**:
The inner radius, use this to create a donut. Takes either percentages or absolute numbers (pixels)

**outerRadius**:
The outer radius, use this to tweak how close your pie is to the edge of it's container. Takes either percentages or absolute numbers (pixels)

I would play around with the two props to achieve the result like in the screenshot above.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @realarb this work for me ```<PieChart style={{ height: '100%', top: 20 }} data={pieData} strokeWidth={0.2} outerRadius={30} />```,**outerRadius**